# How to connect puzzles so that right edge has same length as left edge of another puzzle?

Tags: c, arrays, puzzle

I have puzzles that looks like this:

```
    === ==== 
=== ===
    === ====
```

left edge has length from 0 to 10 000 and right also, middle part is from 1 to 10 000.
So the question is if i can build a rectangle? like first puzzle has length of left edge equal to 0 and the last puzzle has right edge of length 0 and in the middle they fit perfectly?

I am given the number of puzzle i have and their params like this:

```
6
1 9 2
0 3 1
0 4 1
8 9 0
2 9 0
1 5 0
```

and result can be any of that:

```
2
0 3 1
1 5 0
```

or

```
3
0 3 1
1 9 2
2 9 0
```

or

```
2
0 4 1
1 5 0
```

But if there is no result i have to `printf("no result")`

I have to do this in C, I thought about doing some tree and searching it with BFS where vertices would have edge lengths and edge would have middle length and when reached 0 i would go all way up and collect numbers but it's hard to code. So i decided to do recursion but im also stuck:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);//here i get how many puzzles i have
    int tab[a][3];//array for puzzles
    int result[][3];//result array
    int k = 0;//this will help me track how many puzzles has my result array

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){//upload puzzles to array
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d", &tab[i][j]);
        }
    }

    findx(0, a, tab, result, k);//start of recursion, because start has to be length 0

}
int findx(int x, int a, int *tab[], int *result[], int k){//i am looking for puzzle with length x on start
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        if(tab[a][0] == x){//there i look for puzzles with x length at start
            if(tab[a][2] == 0){//if i find such puzzle i check if this is puzzle with edge length zero at the end
                for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){//this for loop add to my result array last puzzle
                    result[k][m] = tab[a][m];
                }
                return print_result(result, k);//we will return result go to print_result function
            }
            else{//if i have puzzle with x length on the left and this is not puzzle which ends rectangle i add this puzzle
                    //to my result array and again look for puzzle with x equal to end length of puzzle i found there
                for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
                    result[k][m] = tab[a][m];
                    k += 1;
                }
                findx(tab[a][2], a, tab, result, k);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("no result");
}

int print_result(int *result[], int k){
    printf("%d", &k);//how many puzzles i have
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){//printing puzzles...
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d ", &result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");//...in separate lines
    }
}
```

I have an error that result array can't look like this `int result[][3]` because of of `[]` but I don't know how many puzzles I'm gonna use so?... and I have implicit declaration for both of my functions. Guys please help, I dont know much about C and its super hard to solve this problem.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is hard to follow.  If you don't know how big result can be you *should* be doing some sort of dynamic memory allocation for result.  Arrays should be treated as fixed size.  It seems the guiding variable for this is `k`?  Maybe that should be renamed to something more significant.  Passing `k` to `findx` is pointless in this case because it is not going to retain its value in that function.  You could just define it in `findx` since it serves no purpose in `main`.

Comment: Also, you are defining functions with return type `int`, but you are not returning anything.  Should these be `void` functions?

Comment: Is `10 000` `10,000`?  Excluding the comma makes it harder to read.

Comment: @Jason I know that i can get max 200 000 puzzels. I changed to void these functions. I made k in main so that this wont be changed in findx because this is recursion and i dont want it to be zero in every loop of this recursion, i changed name from k to puzzelsinresult. But still my program doesnt work. Also i changed size of result to [20000][3] so if result is less then that it will print just tone od nothing at the end of real result.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes 10 000 = 10,000 = ten thousand and 200 000 = 200,000 = two hundred thousands

Comment: Yeah, there are a handful of issues here.  I will work on it.  I would recommend in the future turning on all warnings.  Not sure how you are developing, but for gcc, you would use the -Wall flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the overall logic of the problem, but you definitely are in need of some variable sized containers for result AND tab.  Arrays are fixed size and must be defined at compile time.  The following should at least compile without warnings:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print_result(int (*result)[3], int k){
    printf("%d", k);//how many puzzles i have
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++){//printing puzzles...
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d ", result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");//...in separate lines
    }
}

void findx(int x, int a, int (*tab)[3], int (*result)[3], int k){//i am looking for puzzle with length x on start
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        if(tab[i][0] == x){//there i look for puzzles with x length at start
            if(tab[i][2] == 0){//if i find such puzzle i check if this is puzzle with edge length zero at the end
                for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){//this for loop add to my result array last puzzle
                    result[k][m] = tab[i][m];
                }
                print_result(result, k);//we will return result go to print_result function
                return;
            }
            else{//if i have puzzle with x length on the left and this is not puzzle which ends rectangle i add this puzzle
                    //to my result array and again look for puzzle with x equal to end length of puzzle i found there
                for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
                    result[k][m] = tab[i][m];
                    k += 1;
                    ///** Increase size of result **/
                    //int (*newptr)[3] = realloc(result, (k+1) * sizeof(int[3]));
                    //if (newptr)
                    //    result = newptr;
                }
                findx(tab[i][2], a, tab, result, k);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("no result\n");
}

int main(){

    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);//here i get how many puzzles i have
    int (*tab)[3] = malloc(a * sizeof(int[3]));//array for puzzles
    int (*result)[3] = malloc(a * sizeof(int[3]));//array for puzzles

    int k = 0;//this will help me track how many puzzles has my result array

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){//upload puzzles to array
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d", &tab[i][j]);
        }
    }

    findx(0, a, tab, result, k);//start of recursion, because start has to be length 0

}
```

Note that I changed the tab and result types to `(*int)[3]`.  Due to order of operations,  we need parentheses here.  Because they are variable size, they require dynamic memory allocations.  In the interest of brevity and readability, I did not check the returned values of `malloc` or `realloc`.  In practice, you should be checking that the returned pointer is not `NULL`.  <s>Because we are using dynamic memory allocations, we should also use `free` if you plan on doing anything else with this program.  Otherwise,</s> it doesn't really matter because exiting the program will free the resources anyway.  You actually don't want to free.  because we are passing a pointer by value to `findx` and the `realloc` can change the address, it may come back with a different address.  Also, take note that I needed to `include <stdlib.h>` for the dynamic memory allocations.

**Additional Issues**

Your functions `print_results` and `findx` are not declared when you call them in `main`.  Your function either need to be above main or have "function prototypes" above `main`.

In the `printf`s you do not need the `&`.  You do not want to send the address of the variable to `printf`.  You want to send what will actually be printed.

**Now what?**

The program still does not provide you with the correct results.  It simply outputs 0 as the result every time.  This should at least give you a starting point.  By changing this line in `print_results`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){//printing puzzles...
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++){//printing puzzles...
```

I was at least able to output `0 0 0`.  This seems more correct because if k is 0, we don't loop at all.

Comment: Thanks Jason, you helped me a lot I think i see one problem ```for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
                     result[k][m] = tab[a][m];
                     k += 1;
                     /** Increase size of result **/
                     int (*newptr)[3] = realloc(result, (k+1) * sizeof(int[3]));
                     if (newptr)
                         result = newptr;``` here we increase k every time, but we dont want that, you understand? and can you explain what this increase size of result does?

Comment: @SaltyDog The `realloc` is needed to grow the "size" of `result`.  If `result` is always the same size as `tab`, we can actually `malloc` all the necessary memory up front in `main` like we do for `tab`.  This actually just pointed me to a bug.  In `main`, we should be multiplying `sizeof` by `a` in the `malloc` for `tab`. This is fixed in the answer.

Comment: @SaltyDog  I think I figured it out. I've update the answer.  All throughout `findx`, you are referencing `tab[a][...]`.  First `a` is actually out of range of the array.  In your example, `a` would be 6 so you max array index is 5.  If you replace all the `tab[a][...]` with `tab[i][...]` in `findx`, you will get results.

Comment: I wrote version which is working but loopin with example: given two puzzles first 0 2 2 and second 2 2 2 because 2 2 2 is finding itself so after i will solve this problem i will update question with answer :)) Thank you very much Jason you helped me a lot!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void findx(int x, int a, int tab[a][3], int result[200000][3], int puzzlesinresult) { //i am looking for puzzle with length x on start
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    if (tab[i][0] == x) { //there i look for puzzles with x length at start
      if (tab[i][2] == 0) { //if i find such puzzle i check if this is puzzle with edge length zero at the end
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) { //this for loop add to my result array last puzzle
          result[puzzlesinresult][m] = tab[i][m];
        }
        return print_result(result, puzzlesinresult); //we will return result go to print_result function
      } else { //if i have puzzle with x length on the left and this is not puzzle which ends rectangle i add this puzzle
        //to my result array and again look for puzzle with x equal to end length of puzzle i found there
        while (result[puzzlesinresult - 1][2] != tab[i][0] && puzzlesinresult > 0) {
          puzzlesinresult -= 1;
        }
        int isusedpuzzle = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < puzzlesinresult; j++) {
          if (result[j][0] == tab[i][0] && result[j][1] == tab[i][1] && result[j][2] == tab[i][2]) {
            isusedpuzzle = 1;
          } else {
            //pass
          }
        }
        if (isusedpuzzle == 0) {
          for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
            result[puzzlesinresult][m] = tab[i][m];
          }
          puzzlesinresult += 1;
          findx(tab[i][2], a, tab, result, puzzlesinresult);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void print_result(int result[200000][3], int puzzlesinresult) {
  printf("%d\n", puzzlesinresult + 1); //how many puzzles i have
  for (int i = 0; i < puzzlesinresult + 1; i++) { //printing puzzles...
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%d ", result[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n"); //...in separate lines
  }
  exit(0);
}

int main() {

  int a;
  scanf("%d", & a); //here i get how many puzzles i have
  int tab[a][3]; //array for puzzles
  int result[100][3]; //result array
  int puzzlesinresult = 0; //this will help me track how many puzzles has my result array

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) { //upload puzzles to array
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      scanf("%d", & tab[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) { //here i delete puzzles that doesnt contribute anything like 1 x 1,2 x 2,..
    if (tab[i][0] == tab[i][2] && tab[i][0] != 0) {
      for (int p = i; p < a; p++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          tab[p][j] = tab[p + 1][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  findx(0, a, tab, result, puzzlesinresult); //start of recursion, because start has to be length 0
  printf("NONE");
}
```

This returns sometimes correct result. If you can find when this program fails I would rly appreciate sharing those cases with me :)